# User data is stored in database but user is not directed to email confirmation page

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to add new users but I'm encountering an error saying Call to undefined method `App\User::validate()`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. If anyone can teach me please.

**RedirectIfAuthenticated.php:**

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request); /* I am having the problem here */
    }
}
```

**User.php:**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}

public function checkRoles($roles)
{
    if ( ! is_array($roles)) {
        $roles = [$roles];
    }

    if ( ! $this->hasAnyRole($roles)) {
        auth()->logout();
        abort(404);
    }
}

public function hasAnyRole($roles): bool
{
    return (bool) $this->roles()->whereIn('name', $roles)->first();
}

public function hasRole($role): bool
{
    return (bool) $this->roles()->where('name', $role)->first();
}
```

Comment: please be more specific when your error occurs

Comment: code formatting

Comment: Use `use ValidateRequests;` maybe as a trait?